# No database selected error MYSQL to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
function execute($rsql=null) {
global $db_hostname,
$db_username,
$db_password,
$db_name;   
$conn = mysql_connect($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password) or die ("Error: could not connect to database");
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$db_hostname', $db_username, $db_password); // I TRIED THIS
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
mysql_select_db($db_name);
if($rsql != null){
  $result = mysql_query($rsql) or die (mysql_error()); 
  return $result;     
  mysql_close($conn);
}else{
  define('conn',$conn);
}
```

}

Hi guys, I have the this error: When I change `$conn = mysql_connect($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password) or die ("Error: could not connect to database");` to **PDO** appears in my page: `No database selected.` Can anyone help me?

Comment: maybe if you put your actual change in there

Comment: show your PDO connection code, what you write ? don't show previous one show latest one. or put both connection code it will be more good

Comment: You say the change to PDO doesn't work, but your PDO code _isnt in the question_. we're not mindreaders.

Comment: All you have done is over write your `mysql ` connection with a PDO connection. You can't mix the APIS so all your calls to `mysql_*()` will probably fail.

Comment: But.. It's a big script, with to many files... :c more than 700 files, I can't change everything :(

Comment: then change nothing - its all or nothing baby

Comment: refactoring is easy and fun! .... said noone, ever.

Comment: you've been helped - at least within the context of the question. any more help on this sounds like employment.